# Unity InjectionConstructor for multiparam constructor overriding only single one

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have a class with constructor like this:

```
public class Bar
{
    public Bar(IFoo foo, IFoo2 foo2, IFoo3 foo3, IFooN fooN, String text)
    {

    }
}
```

I want to register Bar in Unity and provide a value for text:

```
unity.RegisterType<Bar, Bar>(new InjectionConstructor("123"));
```

However I can't do this because there is no single parameter constructor for Bar.

Is there a way to provide a value for text without specifying all other parameters as `ResolvedParameter<IFooN>` etc.. I really don't like it, lot's of code, and every time I change a constructor of Bar I need to add another ResolvedParameter

Comment: FWIW, This is so easy in AutoFac out of the box: `builder.RegisterType<Bar>() .WithParameter("text", "the text value")`

Answer (score 49):

Unity can't do this out of the box. The best you can do is:

```cs
container.RegisterType<Bar>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        typeof(IFoo), typeof(IFoo2), typeof(IFoo3), typeof(IFooN), "123"));
```

Or you can use the `SmartConstructor` provided by the [TecX](http://tecx.codeplex.com) project. [This blog post](http://outlawtrail.wordpress.com/2012/08/02/fun-with-constructor-arguments-part-1-pick-choose/) describes some background.

Registration would look like this:

```cs
container.RegisterType<Bar>(new SmartConstructor("text", "123"));
```

Comment: If you need to pass null instead of "123" you will need to use new InjectionParameter<string>(null)

Comment: Using typeof(IFoo) saved me, I couldn't figure out what to pass to the InjectionConstructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Register<TFrom>(params object[] constructorParams) where TFrom : class
        {
            _container.RegisterType<TFrom>(new InjectionConstructor(constructorParams));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to do that as described in the answer above (that's using `InjectionConstructor`). The problem with that is that if the signature of the constructor is changed but `InjectionConstructor` is not updated, then we will know that only at run time. I think that there is a cleaner way to do that and without getting deep into details of the signature of the constructor. Here is how:

```
public interface IBar
{
    void DoSomethingWithBar();
}

public interface IMyStringPrameterForBar
{
    string Value { get; }
}

public class MyStringPrameterForBar : IMyStringPrameterForBar
{
    public string Value { get; }
    public MyStringPrameterForBar(string value) => Value = value; 
}

public class Bar : IBar
{
    public Bar(IFoo foo, IFoo2 foo2, IFoo3 foo3, IFooN fooN, IMyStringPrameterForBar text)
    {
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithBar() {}
}
```

Then when registering interfaces, just add:

```
unity.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>();
unity.RegisterType<IFoo2, Foo2>();
unity.RegisterType<IFooN, FooN>();
unity.RegisterInstance(new MyStrignPrameterForBar("123"));
unity.RegisterType<IBar, Bar>();
```

That's all. if tomorrow `Bar` needs to take more or less parameters, then after adding or removing extra `Foo<N + 1>` Unity will still automatically construct `Bar`.

PS I don't think that interface `IMyStringPrameterForBar` is actually required. However, I prefer to see only interfaces in Unity registrations because it is much easier to twist them around during tests and/or for any other purpose.