# I have to declare all parameters with InjectionConstructor

Tags: c#, unity-container

I need resolve various calls to my class constructor "UnitOfWork" as you can see in the example:

```
container.RegisterType<IDbContext, NorthwindContext>("NorthwindContext");
container.RegisterType<IDbContext, NorthwindCustomerContext>("NorthwindCustomerContext");

container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(
    "NorthwindUnitOfWork", 
    new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<IDbContext>("NorthwindContext")));

container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(
    "NorthwindCustomerUnitOfWork", 
    new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<IDbContext>("NorthwindCustomerContext")));
```

But now I need to add new parameter to the constructor, like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IOtherParameter, OtherParameter>();

container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(
    "NorthwindUnitOfWork", 
    new InjectionConstructor(
        container.Resolve<IDbContext>("NorthwindContext"), 
        container.Resolve<IOtherParameter>()
    ));
```

How can I do if I have many parameters but I only need resolve one and avoid calling `container.Resolve` repeatedly?, like the first example, because `IOtherParameter` only has one option (`RegisterType`). Other respondents like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11871600/138071) saw the library using `SmartConstructor` of [tecx](http://tecx.codeplex.com/), but would need to know if there is any solution in Unity 3 to avoid adding an additional library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity: Implicit ResolvedParameter for unnamed registrations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905504/unity-implicit-resolvedparameter-for-unnamed-registrations/22030760).

Comment: @TylerOhlsen I tried that you sent and it works fine, thanks, now I pass the question as a duplicate